# $3\cos(x+1) =\cos(x+2)$. This is a equation, involving trigonometric functions.

Tags: trigonometry

This actually derives from the same equation though without the parentheses.
Honestly, I haven't learn about the stuff yet. And I don't know if there is a answer for the problem.

Comment: My professor said it is just hard to solve.

Comment: Is you question to solve the equation $3\cos(x+1)=\cos(x+2)$?

Comment: Hint: First let $y = x+1$ to save yourself a little bit of grief, then use the cosine angle sum formula.

Comment: @user7530 [nope. that doesn't help at all](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3cos(x%2B1)%3Dcos(x%2B2)) this might have been an example of seemingly simple but hard to solve questions. let's leave it at that.

Comment: @Sabyasachi: It absolutely does help. The answer isn't entirely simple, but you can make it considerably simpler than Wolfram Alpha makes it out to be.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Have you tried it? It's actually one of those examples where Wolfram Alpha goes off of the deep end for what is actually quite a simple problem ;)

Comment: @user7530i know it can be solved. i don't see *why* i want to solve this. :[

Answer (score 4):

$$3\cos(x+1)=\cos(x+2)$$
Let $y=x+1$

$$3\cos(y)=\cos(y+1)$$

$$3\cos(y)=\cos(y)\cos(1)-\sin(y)\sin(1)$$

$$3\cos(y)-\cos(y)\cos(1)=-\sin(y)\sin(1)$$

$$\cos(y)(3-\cos(1))=-\sin(y)\sin(1)$$

$$- \dfrac{3-\cos(1)}{\sin(1)}=\tan(y)$$

I think you can take over from there.

Comment: Could you please better your answer by adding the name of the identities you used.

Comment: Yes,sure. The two identities I used are $\tan(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ and $\cos(x+y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$

Answer (score 1):

Following from user7530 it seems that using the substitution does appear to work.

$$3 \cos(x+1)=\cos(x+2)$$
let $y=x+1$ therefore giving the equation: 
$$3 \cos(y)=\cos(y+1) $$
We can now use the cosine sum identity: $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$ to give:

$$ 3\cos(y)=\cos(y) \cos (1)-\sin(y) \sin(1) $$
After a little rearrangement we get the formula:
$$ \tan(y)=\frac{\cos(1)-3}{\sin(1)} $$
Thus after taking the inverse tangent of both sides (remembering to include $n \pi$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ to include the repeating solutions).
$$ y=\tan^{-1}((\cos(1)-3) \,/ \sin(1)) +n \pi$$
Therefore after replacing the substitution we made that $y=x+1$ gives the value of $x$ to be:

$$x=\tan^{-1}((\cos(1)-3) \,/ \sin(1)) -1 +n \pi$$